# How can I have two haskell platform working separately

Tags: haskell

I am using debian and the haskell-platform on the system gets really old. So I download the newest haskel-platform binary version and place it under /usr/local/haskell and activate it. Now there're 2 versions of ghc. If I type ghc then the old ghc-7.4 will be used and ghc-7.8.3 will certainly call the new one. But I have trouble with cabal. The new cabal cannot be used because of glibc version. Can I make the old cabal work with the new haskell platform ? If so how can I make it work just like there're two cabals. In the other word, I want the default directory of the cabal working with the old platform to still remain `$HOME/.cabal` and the cabal working with new platform to become the new directory (actually I don't know where). Can anyone help me to configure it so that I can have two versions of haskell-platform working separately on my Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lots of GHC installations at the same time without problems, but I don't think that's true for multiple Cabal installations. All you need is to use up-to-date Cabal, no need to keep any other versions. See this blog post for how to use multiple GHC's: http://osa1.net/posts/2014-12-09-ghc-cabal-installation-guide.html